# How to keep a class "alive" (...and passing the same NodeHandle)?

Tags: ros, nodehandle, timer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
here the minimal example I could create to explain a problem with my program which is splitted into 2 classes. One class creates an istance of the second one:

Let's start with the main file:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "include/foo.h"
#include "include/bar.h"
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
   ros::init( argc, argv, "main_node" );
   ros::NodeHandle nh;
   ros::NodeHandle nh_private( "~" );
    
    boost::scoped_ptr<Foo> trajectory( new Foo( nh, nh_private ) );
    ROS_INFO( "Waiting some seconds..." ); // Just for fun
    ros::Duration(3.0).sleep();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The class Foo has a constructor which initialize the class and later, thtough an internal function, create an istance of the second class.

```
class Foo {
    private:
     /* private variables here */

    private:
    void initParam();
    /* of course here there are much more functions already implemented.... */

}
```

in `initParam()` I have the following creation of the last class:

```
void initParam()  // A method defined in Foo
{
 /* code code code...*/
  boost::scoped_ptr<Bar> way( new Bar( nh_ ) ); // <- !!!! Here is the same NodeHdandle of the master class pased by VALUE
  way->amIAlive(); // <- Yes it is....the call is working
  ROS_INFO( "Getting a random value: %6.4f", way->generateValues() ) // <-working perfectly here too
  /*...*/
}
```

and lately the class Bar in which I have defined a **timer** to **publish some data regularly**:

```
class Bar {
   Bar::Bar( ros::NodeHandle nh ): nh_(nh) {

    marker_pub_ = nh_.advertise<visualization_msgs::MarkerArray>( "visualization_marker_array", 10 ); // To publish data on RViz
   
  ros::Timer timeloop_ = nh_.createTimer( ros::Duration( set_duration_time_ ), &Bar::publishPoints, this ); // Nothing...here doesn't publish anything... Why!?!?

void Bar::publishPoints( const ros::TimerEvent& event ) const {
    /* publish the markers */
    marker_pub_.publish( marker_array_ );
}
}
```

So guys...the problem.
The problem is the second class (Bar) gets the node passed by value but doesn't publish anything.
Doing:

> $ rostopic echo
> /visualization_marker_array

stucks all the time.
Other functions implemented in the class are working correctly and I get the calculation for the points in the right way.
What could be the reason?

I put some comments in the constrctors and destructors of both classes to see where could be the problem and here is the output:

```
me@YE-166:~/workspace_ros$ rosrun my_pkg my_prog
[ INFO] [1417875069.502609530]: Constructor of the Foo class has been called
[ INFO] [1417875069.505375417]: Constructor of the Bar class has been called
[ INFO] [1417875069.505837985]: Valid number of requested waypoints
[ INFO] [1417875072.506157010]: Number of points: 7
[ WARN] [1417875072.506273683]: Calling Destructor of the Bar's class...
[ INFO] [1417875072.508900594]: Waiting some seconds...
[ WARN] [1417875075.509383455]: Calling Destructor of the Foo's Class...
me@YE-166:~/workspace_ros$
```

Seems to working correctly but I suppose (and it is my opinion) that the class Bar doesn't have the time to publish data on the topic. Fpor that reasons I put a waiting function inside of it to give it time. But it doesn't help.
The class runs the function Bar::publishPoints() which is time event function and it is suppose to run all the time. But get destroy with the class

2 things I have:

- I want to be able to publish data from the second class Bar passing the nodehandle (doesn't matter how: pointer, value, reference...);
- The timed function must run all the time in background. So the class Bar must not be destroyed;

Could you give me some help?
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199017/how-to-keep-a-class-%22alive%22-(...and-passing-the-same-nodehandle)-?/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-12-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-12-06**:
Is there a `spin` or `spinOnce` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @kramer has pointed out, you have no ros::spin() function in your main, meaning that a) no callbacks get processed and b) main returns immediately, destroying Foo.

Even after adding ros::spin(), Bar will still die earlier than you expect, because it will be destroyed when the initParam function returns.

Please read about lifetime, scope, and blocking on stackoverflow.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2014-12-06**:
For clarity: a `Timer` uses ROS's callback mechanism for its operation; without a spin, the `publishPoints` method will never be called.

I totally overlooked Bar's scope and destruction...nice catch, @paulbovbel.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-12-07**:
Ok, guys. Thanks. a lot. A didn't know, that a timer has the same callback like messages and topics.
About the scope of a class I agree with you, but I was sure that the running timer doesn't let the function to return. The visibility is right, but I misunderstood how a timer is currently working.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-12-07**:
createTimer does return immediately. And then the timer object goes out of scope, so it won't be running anymore. Just like with pub/sub, you need the object to be in scope (i.e. be a member of the class and not just temporary on the heap), and you need ros::spin to process callbacks.